# Disallow usage of imported elements as root

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

How do I prevent globally defined elements in imported XSDs from being allowed to be root elements in valid XML documents?

### a.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://example.org/a" elementFormDefault="qualified"
 xmlns="http://example.org/a" xmlns:ns="http://example.org/a"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="elementA">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="x">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:key name="keyX">
      <xs:selector xpath="ns:x"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
    </xs:key>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

### b.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://example.org/b" elementFormDefault="qualified"
 xmlns="http://example.org/b" xmlns:a="http://example.org/a"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:import schemaLocation="a.xsd" namespace="http://example.org/a"/>
  <xs:element name="elementB">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element ref="a:elementA"/>
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The problem I have is that, when validating an XML file against b.xsd, `elementA` is a valid root element (because of the import). How do I change the schemas such that `elementB` is the only valid root element? Note that I do need the key inside `elementA`, which makes this harder than other similar cases I've found on SO.

Answer (score 1):

XSD does not specify which top-level element declarations or type definitions are allowed to be the ones at which validation begins.  The design is for that to be specified at validation time.  Since the XSD spec doesn't prescribe a particular interface for invoking validation, the details of the mechanism you use for this will vary (and not all validators have clued into the fact that they ought to allow the user to specify the expected element or type of the root at validation time.

If the software you're using for validation has invocation-time options or parameters for specifying what element declaration(s) are acceptable at the validation root, use them.  If it doesn't, use application-level code to make sure you're dealing not just with a valid element but one that your code is prepared to deal with.

Comment: I've now created a method which calls the normal validation, but also checks if the root element has the correct name.

Answer (score 0):

If an element is globally defined in an XSD, directly or via import or include, it may be used as the root element.  If you don't want root element options opened up by imports or includes, then declare no global elements in the imported or included XSDs – **use all locally declared elements in defining the composition of the root element**.

You can still, of course, define types in the imported and included XSDs.

Comment: Problem with types is they cannot contain keys, which I do need.